# How can I get EclipseLink to output valid Informix SQL for an UPDATE WHERE clause?

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, informix

We have a named query like this:

```
UPDATE Foo f SET f.x = 0 WHERE f.x = :invoiceId
```

`Foo` in this case is an entity with a superclass, using the table-per-class inheritance strategy.

The SQL that EclipseLink generates is:

```
UPDATE foo_subclass SET x = ?
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT t0.id
                FROM foo_superclass t0, foo_subclass t1
               WHERE ((t1.x = ?) AND ((t1.id = t0.id) AND (t0.DTYPE = ?)))
```

(The `?` slots are correctly filled in.)

On Informix 11.70, we get an error that the subquery cannot access the table being changed.

Here is the documentation that I was able to find on subquery restrictions on Informix: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_2005.htm

Other databases also feature restrictions on subqueries like this, so although this is manifesting as an Informix issue, I'm sure that if we ran this against, say, MySQL, we would get a similar error.

How can I get EclipseLink to honor these restrictions?  Is there a better query I should be using?

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using?  You reference the 11.50 InfoCenter, so I guess you're using 11.50. However, since the equivalent page in 11.70 ([Subqueries in the WHERE Clause of UPDATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2005.htm)) contains the same information, it probably isn't a major issue this time (but always state the version of Informix you are using, and the platform too; it often matters).

Comment: Amending answer; it's 11.70.

Comment: Which DatabasePlattform does EclipseLink detect on connect (should be printed to your log)? Does it correctly detect Informix?

Comment: It does.  The stock `InformixPlatform` has several problems, so I actually have a `SessionCustomizer` that installs my subclass of it (overrides `appendBooleanAsLiteral` for one thing).  For most purposes they're identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  Looks like EclipseLink had to handle this case for MySQL, which also has similar issues.

The answer is that in your `InformixPlatform` subclass, you need to override the following methods to solve this problem:

1. `supportsLocalTemporaryTables()`: this needs to return `true`
2. `shouldAlwaysUseTempStorageForModifyAll()`: this needs to return `true`
3. `dontBindUpdateAllQueryUsingTempTables` needs to return `true`
4. `getCreateTempTableSqlPrefix()`: this needs to return `CREATE TEMP TABLE`
5. `getCreateTempTableSqlSuffix()`: this needs to return  `WITH NO LOG`
6. `isInformixOuterJoin()`: needs to return `false`
7. `getTempTableForTable(DatabaseTable)`: this needs to do this:

   ```
   return new DatabaseTable("TL_" + table.getName(), "" /* no table qualifier */, table.shouldUseDelimiters(), this.getStartDelimiter(), this.getEndDelimiter());
   ```

In addition, you need to override the following methods as well for proper `InformixPlatform` behavior:

1. `appendBoolean(Boolean, Writer)`: the stock Informix platform does not write out boolean literals properly.  Yours needs to do this:

   ```
   if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(booleanValue)) {
     writer.write("'t'");
   } else {
     writer.write("'f'");
   }
   ```
2. You need to override `writeUpdateOriginalFromTempTableSql` so that it contains the same code as the `H2Platform`'s override does:

   ```
   @Override
   public void writeUpdateOriginalFromTempTableSql(final Writer writer, final DatabaseTable table, final Collection pkFields, final Collection assignedFields) throws IOException {
     writer.write("UPDATE ");
     final String tableName = table.getQualifiedNameDelimited(this);    
     writer.write(tableName);
     writer.write(" SET ");
     final int size = assignedFields.size();
     if (size > 1) {
       writer.write("(");            
     }
     writeFieldsList(writer, assignedFields, this);
     if (size > 1) {
       writer.write(")");            
     }
     writer.write(" = (SELECT ");        
     writeFieldsList(writer, assignedFields, this);
     writer.write(" FROM ");
     final String tempTableName = this.getTempTableForTable(table).getQualifiedNameDelimited(this);
     writer.write(tempTableName);
     writeAutoJoinWhereClause(writer, null, tableName, pkFields, this);
     writer.write(") WHERE EXISTS(SELECT ");
     writer.write(((DatabaseField)pkFields.iterator().next()).getNameDelimited(this));
     writer.write(" FROM ");
     writer.write(tempTableName);
     writeAutoJoinWhereClause(writer, null, tableName, pkFields, this);
     writer.write(")");
   }
   ```

Lastly, your constructor needs to call `this.setShouldBindLiterals(false)`.

With these changes, it seems that Informix is happy.

Comment: The plot thickens; still more stuff to go here.  (For those following along.)  Need to override several other methods as well, including the temp table prefix and suffix methods (to add `WITH NO LOG` at the end for one thing)).  Now the Informix platform is dropping the temp tables before insertion.  That's up to be fixed next.  It is clear this platform hasn't been tested in ages.

Comment: Next up, Informix does not support qualifying `TEMP TABLE` names with schema/owner prefixes.  This--coupled with the fact that EclipseLink ignores (!) all errors (!!) from the statements that actually attempt the `CREATE TEMP TABLE` operations means that the syntax error that results from trying to create a temp table with a schema prefix is hidden/swallowed.  More patches to the platform coming up.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
UPDATE foo_subclass SET x = ?
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT t0.id
                FROM foo_superclass t0, foo_subclass t1
               WHERE ((t1.x = ?) AND ((t1.id = t0.id) AND (t0.DTYPE = ?)))
```

do this:

```
UPDATE
  foo_subclass SET x = ?
WHERE
  foo_subclass.x = ? AND
  EXISTS(SELECT t0.id
         FROM foo_superclass t0
         WHERE ((foo_subclass.id = t0.id) AND (t0.DTYPE = ?))
```

Note that on 11.50 you cannot use alias for foo_subclass. It's allowed in 11.70.
I'm assuming "id" are primary keys (or at least unique identifiers).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think I can.  EclipseLink controls the SQL syntax. We are running against 11.70. And yes, `id` in my example is the primary key of the table in question.

Comment: May I ask what the syntax problem is?  Why does Informix not like the SQL that EclipseLink creates?

Comment: @LairdNelson: It isn't a syntax problem; it is a semantic issue.  The concern behind the restrictions is whether the table changes while the query is being processed, thus causing stability issues in the data set to be updated.  How serious those are, and whether there's a half-way decent way around them, is open for discussion, but the restriction has been in place since time immemorial.

Comment: @LairdNelson: I'm curious about why the EXISTS query is necessary.  If the tables (`foo_superclass` and `foo_subclass`) are in a state of semantic integrity — no broken (or missing) foreign key constraints, there's no need for the check that the row in the sub-class belongs in the sub-class, is there?  Or, if there is, what don't we know about the schemas of the two tables?

Comment: Bulk update in JPA operates on the class, not the table.  It is only allowed to touch Foo classes, and there is no way for it to do that without the exists joining it to the root table so it can use the Type to filter.  Other classes or other applications might also use the foo_subclass table in some way that should not be affected by this query.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, when Fernando originally answered my question, he mentioned that he was unable to test.  Do your edits to the answer constitute changes that I should look into overriding in my bugfix platform class for EclipseLink?  That is, is this a simple aliasing problem (bearing in mind Chris' comment above as to why the `EXISTS` query is necessary)?

Comment: No - my edits simply indented the SQL so it appears as code, not as running text.  I've not tested the SQL; I'm a little worried that it doesn't meet the prescriptions on the page you reference, still.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes, you and me both. What steps could I (in my bugfix override) or EclipseLink (in the real thing) take, bearing in mind Chris' comments, to meet the restrictions of the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Oh, and your edit did remove a `foo_subclass` reference in the `FROM` clause. I wasn't sure if that was significant or not.

Comment: That was unintentional — a mistake — if it happened.  But, AFAICS from the edit, I did not change that.